# IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier

Tags: c#, .net, security, wcf-security, jwt

What might the reason be that I get the exception below when trying to validate a token.

```
TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();

validationParameters.ValidIssuers = new List<string>() { "http://www.company.com" };

validationParameters.IssuerSigningToken = new RsaSecurityToken(
  (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider) Certificate.Get().PublicKey.Key);

SecurityToken securityToken = null;

var claimsPrincipal = 
    (FederatedAuthentication
      .FederationConfiguration
      .IdentityConfiguration
      .SecurityTokenHandlers
      .First() as JwtSecurityTokenHandler)
      .ValidateToken(tokenString, validationParameters, out securityToken);
```

**Error**:

```
IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 
          'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
      IsReadOnly = False,
      Count = 2,
      Clause[0] = X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(
                    Hash = 0x6B7ACC520305BFDB4F7252DAEB2177CC091FAAE1),
    Clause[1] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
', 
token: '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657307/securitytokensignaturekeynotfoundexception-when-validating-jwt-signature might offer some interesting details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring signature in JWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892788/ignoring-signature-in-jwt)

Comment: Is the certificate you trying to use to validate the token, is installed in Root Certificate store (if its dev certificate)  ?

Comment: does your token have a "kid" property?

Answer (score 1):

From the error, I think you need to add an x509  Security key or credentials, something like this:

```
var credentials = new X509CertificateCredentials(
    Certificate.Get(),
    new SecurityKeyIdentifier(
        new NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause(
            "kid",
            "6B7ACC520305BFDB4F7252DAEB2177CC091FAAE1")));
```

eg this part:

```
new SecurityKeyIdentifier(
        new NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause(
            "kid",
            "6B7ACC520305BFDB4F7252DAEB2177CC091FAAE1")
```

Also, make sure your certificate is installed in your root store.